# java.net.SocketTimeoutException on embedded tomcat with jersey

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, embedded-tomcat-7

My server application use embedded tomcat with Jersey.
From time to time I'm getting the following error:

```
    02-03-2014 10:06:05 [com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse] [http-nio-8243-exec-4] [ERROR] - The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:246)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:227)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.readSocket(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:419)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.fill(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:789)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:814)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:124)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:346)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:290)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:449)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:315)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:200)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.io.CharStreams.copy(CharStreams.java:202)
    at com.google.common.io.CharStreams.toStringBuilder(CharStreams.java:248)
    at com.google.common.io.CharStreams.toString(CharStreams.java:222)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$VoidOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:167)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1686)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

For a resource that is reading input stream (not that big, ~18K).
I was wondering if there's any configuration I can change that will make my application wait more while reading the input stream.
Is org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector#setAsyncTimeout related to the problem I'm experiencing?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to stop those errors by enlarging Tomcat's read timeout, as follows:

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector#setProperty
```

For example:

```
httpConnector.setProperty("soTimeout", "50000");
```