# Modify SO_TIMEOUT (read timeout) for embedded tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, embedded-tomcat-7

How can I modify the read timeout for embedded tomcat?
From [Apache Tomcat Configuration Reference](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/http.html):

**socket.soTimeout**
Value in milliseconds for the sockets read timeout (SO_TIMEOUT). Default value is 5000 milliseconds.

I've tried the following

> ```
>     httpConnector.setAttribute("channelNioSocket.soTimeout", 1);
>     httpConnector.setAttribute("soTimeout", 1);
>     httpConnector.setAttribute("SO_TIMEOUT", 1);
> ```

I expected to get SocketTimeoutException as I changed the value to 1 millisecond, but didn't, so I assume it's not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.net.SocketTimeoutException on embedded tomcat with jersey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550369/java-net-sockettimeoutexception-on-embedded-tomcat-with-jersey)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector#setProperty
```

For example:

```
httpConnector.setProperty("soTimeout", "50000");
```